# Angular Collision

Tags: angular-momentum, angular-velocity

**Angular Collision**. A uniform rod of mass M and length d is initially at rest on a horizontal and frictionless table in the x-y plane. the figure attached is a top view, with gravity pointing into the page. The rod is free to rotate about an axis perpendicular to the plane and is passing through the pivot point at a distance d/3 measured from one of its ends as shown. A small point particle of mass m = M/4, which is moving with speed $v_0$, hits the rod and sticks to it at the point of impact at a distance d/3 from the pivot.

[image]

$a)$ Find the magnitude of the angular velocity of the rod-and-mass system after the collision.

$b)$ Using again $M = 4m$, find the speed of the centre of mass of the rod right after the collision.

Attempt:

I'm assuming you start to answer this question by using the equation of angular momentum $L = I\omega$ Really confused by this if someone could help me understand the question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no external force acting on the system of ball and the rod except for gravity which acts along the $z$ axis.  Hence no external torque is produced on the system.  We know that 
$$\tau=\frac {d\mathbf L}{dt}$$
$$0=\frac {d\mathbf L}{dt}$$.
Thus the angular momentum is conserved. 
. Hence by conserving angular momentum about the  pivot point we get 
$$\frac {mv_0d}{3}=\frac {(M+m)d^2\omega}{9}$$
Hence we shall get

$$\omega= \frac {3mv_0}{(M+m)d}$$
While for the second part,  by conserving linear momentum we get 
$$mv_0= (m+4m)v_{cm}$$
$$\Rightarrow v_{cm}= \frac {v_0}{5}$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, could you just break down the first and second line of the solution. Thanks @manthanein

Comment: What do you want me to explain exactly?

Comment: @downvoter Why the downvote?